# Sencha Touch change itemTpl on specific items in list

Tags: list, extjs, touch

I'd like to be able to add class in the Itemtpl where the Item has it's field "Answered" set to "true" 
It sound's easy to me, but I don't know where to start..

I know I have to check if Answered is true in the tpl, but I don't know how to write in the template.. o.O

```
        //model
    Ext.define('User', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        config: {
            idProperty: 'Name',
            fields: [
                {name: 'Name', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Address', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'ID', type: 'int'},
                {name: 'WebUrl', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'InfoUrl', type: 'string'},
                {name: 'Answered', type: 'boolean'},
                ]
        }
    });

    //store

    aStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'User',
        sorters: 'Name',
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function(record) {
                return record.get('Name')[0];
            }
        }
    });

    //full store

    store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'User',
        sorters: 'Name',
        grouper: {
            groupFn: function(record) {
                return record.get('Name')[0];
            }
        },
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: '/Services/RestaurantList.ashx',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'users'
            }
        },
        listeners:{
            load: function(){
                var all = store.data.all;
                aStore.setData(all.slice(0,30));
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true
    });


    //the list
    list = Ext.create('Ext.List', {
        flex: 8,
        itemTpl: ['<div class="contact">{Name}</div>'],
        store: aStore,
        listeners: {
            itemtap: function(list, index, target, record) {
                mainContainer.setActiveItem(1);
                detailsPanel.setRecord(record);
        },
        plugins: [
            {
                xclass: 'Ext.plugin.PullRefreshFn',
                refreshFn: function(){
                    store.clearData();
                    aStore.clearData();
                    store.clearFilter();
                    aStore.clearFilter();
                    store.load();
                    list.refresh();
                }
            }
        ],
        grouped: true
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the docs for XTemplate?  http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate.  In particular, look at the "Conditional processing with basic comparison operators" section.

If you don't want to use the `<tpl if="">` notation, you can also use the ternary operator:

```
itemTpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<div class="{[values.Answered ? \'answered\' : \'\']}">{Name}</div>'
),
...
```

Comment: yea.. I figured it out now.. I'm embarrassed that I asked about this here... Thanks anyway, I'll accept the answer :)